# Феминитивы: как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, род, егэ

Как будет правильно: **авторка и писательница** или **автор и писательница**?
Это касается верного ответа на ЕГЭ.

Comment: Верны варианты _автор_ и _писательница_.

Comment: А что, на ЕГЭ уже встречаются такие вопросы?

Comment: @Серж, когда пишешь сочинение, можно столкнуться с такой проблемой - как правильно написать? Вот поэтому и спрашиваю.

Answer (score 3):

При такой формулировке вопроса в ЕГЭ (какой вариант выбрать?) правильным ответом, считаю, может быть только этот:
***автор*** и ***писательница***.

Слово *писательница* используется в языке уже больше двухсот лет.
Из Нацкорпуса:
*...приглашать на сіи чтенія какъ мужчинъ, такъ и женщинъ, изъ которыхъ двѣ **писательницы**, Бунина и Волкова, причислены были къ членамъ сословія* (А. С. Шишков. Записки (**1780–1814**)).

Слово [*авторка*](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CrMBEoYBCoMBChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluEmwKFwoDbGV4EhAKDtCw0LLRgtC%2B0YDQutCwCgoKBGZvcm0SAgoACgsKBWdyYW1tEgIKAAoJCgNzZW0SAgoAChUKB3NlbS1tb2QSCgoIc2VtfHNlbXgKCQoDc3luEgIKAAoLCgVmbGFncxICCgAqIQoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKMrLnN7viPIJQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQEwAQ%3D%3D) (в Нацкорпусе — всего три примера; первый датирован 2017 годом) появилось совсем недавно (мне кажется, как дань идеологии — должно же быть!), в настоящий момент считается неологизмом и широкого его распространения в языке пока не наблюдается.

А литературных феминитивов на *-ка*, конечно же, предостаточно: горожанка, казачка, француженка, христианка, одесситка, японка, арестантка, биатлонистка, алкоголичка, пианистка...

Comment: А есть ли какой-то смысл у окончаний -ка и -ца кроме феминитивного? Например: батарея - батарейка, бумага - бумажка, рубаха - рубашка, рожа - рожица? Да и еще есть же суффикс(?) -ищ-, автор - авторище, но феминитив будет -ща, а не -ще, лужа - лужища, тогда авторища?

Comment: В первом случае суффиксы *-к-* и *-иц-* являются уменьшительно-ласкательными (https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sostav-slova/suffiks/umenshitelno-laskatelnye-suffiksy.html), а во втором — увеличительными (нога — ножища, волк — волчище). Автор**ш**а — суффикс -ш-; автор**ищ**е (искл.) — суффикс -ищ-.

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее распространен феминитив «писательница».
https://burninghut.ru/russkikh-pisatelnic-xix-veka/

Кроме того, в нац. корпусе можно встретить «романистка», «беллетристка» и пр. специализа-ции.
Очень редко употребляется «авторша» и еще реже – «авторесса».

...Чем только не радует авторесса своего читателя! [И взялись за перо дамы // «Витрина читающей России», 2002.09.13]
...Время для фиксации в языке слов «авторка» и «блогерка», за введение которых в
употребление выступают феминистки, еще не пришло. [Появление «авторок» и «блогерок» в словарях отсрочили на десятилетия // lenta.ru, 2019.04.06]

Comment: Это касается правильного написания на **ЕГЭ**.